# Gon gem for ruby on rails watch function watch all variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

gon is a gem for ruby on rails to pass data from controller to view's javascript.

It works fine,just pass data,and watch one variable.

but when I have normal data(no need dynamic watch ) and data1 (need watch )teogeher,problem happens.

Gon watch all variables instead of only watch the gon.watch.data1.

That cause refresh time very very long (7k ms plus)

web page always hang.

anyone face this problem before? how to solve this?

code in my controller

```
class GmapsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @i=0
    @Nstatic=Array.new(NoiseDevice.all.length) {Array.new(4)} 
    @Vstatic=Array.new(VibrationDevice.all.length) {Array.new(4)}     
    @vabrdevices = VibrationDevice.find(:all)

    @vabrdevices.each do |vabrdevice|
    @Vstatic[@i][0]=Project.where(id: vabrdevice.project_id).pluck(:client_name).first.to_s

    @Vstatic[@i][1]=vabrdevice.latitude #
    @Vstatic[@i][2]=vabrdevice.longitude #

    @Vstatic[@i][3]=VibrationDevice.where(id: vabrdevice.id).pluck(:cont_value).first.to_s

    @i+=1
    end

    @i=0
    @noiseDevices = NoiseDevice.find(:all)
    @noiseDevices.each do |noiseDevice|
    @Nstatic[@i][0]=Project.where(id: noiseDevice.project_id).pluck(:client_name).first.to_s
    address=Project.where(id: noiseDevice.project_id).pluck(:jobsite_location).first.gsub(/\s+/, "+")


    @Nstatic[@i][1]=noiseDevice.latitude #
    @Nstatic[@i][2]=noiseDevice.longitude #
    @Nstatic[@i][3]=NoiseDatum.order(:updated_at).where(noise_device_id: noiseDevice.id).pluck(:leq).first.to_s

    @i+=1
    end




    gon.nstatic=@Nstatic
    gon.vstatic=@Vstatic



    end

def ndataupdate
@test=Array.new
@test=VibrationDevice.pluck(:cont_value).to_s
gon.watch.test1=@test

end
end
```

Instead of update my test1 only, it updates all data which is loaded from database in this controller. even if I delete

gon.nstatic=@Nstatic
gon.vstatic=@Vstatic

gon will load all data retrieved from database in this controller instead of part of it.

In order to make it display only refresh part , I delete all retrieve data function ...

Comment: could you write what is in your controller?

Comment: @IS04 updated my controller code

Comment: `ndataupdate` is separate action in your controller? and when you call something like `gon.watch('test1', interval: 1000, 'callback method')` you get all data?

Comment: @IS04 yes,I try separate as I suspect put them in same action will cause gon refresh all.Now separate gon also watchs all.I read from ROR log,it loads all data include this test1 data when fresh every interval time.That cause it takes long.

Comment: you could try write `gon.watch('test1', {interval: 1000, url: 'url to your ndataupdate'}, callback)`, which url it use for getting updates? alos you could check `gon.all_variables` which variables is in your `ndataupdate` action, maybe even try `gon.clear` before set watch variable.

Comment: @IS04 write this to replace gon.watch('test1', interval: 1000, 'callback method') ? then where to set time interval,actual action no need refresh so fast...

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's not answer, but maybe it somehow helps (comments are too long),

so, you could specify manualy `url` for updating variable like:

```
gon.watch('test1', {interval: <ms>, url: '<url>'}, '<callback>')
```

for checking available variables in your `ndataupdate` action you could write:

```
gon.all_variables
```

also you could try cleaning variables with:

```
gon.clear
```

Comment: sry I debug further more, I find out even I delete gon.nstatic and gon.vstatic it still loads all data -- unless I delete load nstatic and vstatic data in controller.I'll edit my question